# shiny: Saving rpivotTableOutput as Excel

Tags: r, excel, shiny, output, rpivottable

I could not figured out how to save the output of [rpivottable](/questions/tagged/rpivottable) in [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny). My minimum working example is below for reference.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "green",
    dashboardHeader(
      title      = "Test",
      titleWidth = 280
      ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 280,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(text = "Output", tabName = "Out1",     icon = icon("file-upload"))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
                 tabName = "Out1",
                 fluidRow(column(width = 10, strong("Data")), align = "center"),
                 br(),
                 fluidRow(rpivotTableOutput("Data1"))
                 ) 
      )
    )
  )

  
server <- 
  function(input, output){
    library(rpivotTable)
      
    output$Data1 <- 
      renderRpivotTable(
        rpivotTable(
            data = mtcars
          , rows = "cyl"
          , cols = "gear"
          , height = "780px"
          )
        )
          }

runApp(
    list(ui = ui, server = server)
  , launch.browser = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: The R object of `rpivotTable` output does not contain the processed pivot table. I think this will be calculated in the JavaScript on the client's browser. So this should not be possible. Do you really need `rpivottable`? Why not simply do `xtabs(~ cyl + class, data = mpg) |> as.data.frame() |> writexl::write_xlsx()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit/Update: with the help of `rvest` and `xlsx` packages, we   can save the extracted html pivot table as xls file. Updated code below**

I agree with @danlooo 's comment that trying to extract data from the render of `rpivotTable` might not be the best way forward. However, I can offer a way of extracting the HTML code of generated pivot table.

Below code extracts the html code of the generated pivot table,  uses rvest to extract a `dataframe` from this html , finally using `xlsx` for export.
More info on interaction between shiny and js can be found [in this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)

The code  generates an xls file containing the  pivot table generated by rpivotTable

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rpivotTable)

library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(xlsx)

ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "green",
    
    dashboardHeader(
      title      = "Test",
      titleWidth = 280
    ),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 280,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(text = "Output", tabName = "Out1")
      ),
      
      hr(),
      useShinyjs(),
      actionButton(inputId = "btnExport", "Export Table")
      
      
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "Out1",
          fluidRow(column(width = 10, strong("Data")), align = "center"),
          br(),
          fluidRow(rpivotTableOutput("Data1"))
        ) 
      )
    )
  )


server <- 
  function(input, output){
    #library(rpivotTable)
    
    output$Data1 <- 
      renderRpivotTable(
        rpivotTable(
          data = mtcars
          , rows = "cyl"
          , cols = "gear"
          , height = "780px"
        )
      )
    
    
    observeEvent(input$btnExport,{
      
      runjs(
        "
        var tblhtml=document.getElementsByClassName('pvtRendererArea')[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(tblhtml)
        //set shiny Input value to read reactively from R 
        Shiny.setInputValue('tblvar_shiny', tblhtml);
        "
      )
      
    } )
    
    #save pivot table to html file
    # observeEvent(input$tblvar_shiny, 
    #              { write_file(sprintf("<html><body> %s </body></html>", 
    #                                   input$tblvar_shiny), 
    #                           file = "000pivothtml.html" )})
    
    #save pivot table to xls file 
    observeEvent(input$tblvar_shiny,
                 { 
                     minimal_html(input$tblvar_shiny) %>% 
                     html_element("table")   %>% 
                     html_table() %>% 
                     as.data.frame() %>% 
                     write.xlsx2(file="000pivot_final.xls")
                   })
  } 

runApp(
  list(ui = ui, server = server)  , launch.browser = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Output very close to required.